# Replacing characters in each line on a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file with different word in each line.
My goal is to replace the first character to a capital letter and replace the 3rd character to "#".

For example: `football` will be exchanged to `Foo#ball`.

I tried thinking about using awk and sed.It didn't help me since (to my knowledge) sed needs an exact character input and awk can print the desired character but not change it.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `sed needs an exact character input`? Completely the opposite, sed cannot operate on an exact character input - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001 for the hoops you have to jump through to make sed act as if it were using literal strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU sed and two `s` commands:

```
echo 'football' | sed -E 's/(.)/\U\1/; s/(...)./\1#/'
```

Output:

```
Foo#ball
```

---

See: [3.3 The s Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed#The-_0022s_0022-Command), [5.7 Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html) and [5.9.2 Upper/Lower case conversion](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed#Upper_002fLower-case-conversion)

Answer (score 2):

With bash you can use parameter expansions alone to accomplish the task. For example, if you read each line into the variable `line`, you can do:

```
line="${line^}"                # change football to Football (capitalize 1st char)
line="${line:0:3}#${line:4}"   # make 4th character '#'
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat file
football
soccer
baseball
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ while read -r line; do line="${line^}"; echo "${line:0:3}#${line:4}"; done < file
Foo#ball
Soc#er
Bas#ball
```

While shell is typically slower, when use is limited to builtins, it doesn't fall too far behind.

(**note:** your question says 3rd character, but your example replaces the 4th character with `'#'`)

Comment: The `read` alone will make it extremely slow compared to a sed or awk solution, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219. Always quote your variables unless you **need** to do something that **requires** them to be unquoted - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. In this case even if we assume there's no spaces in the input you'd get unfortunate results if the input contained globbing chars that just happened to match local file names.

Comment: Yes, this only does about 100,000 lines per-second (with SSD), so if your file is millions, you will want something faster. If you are dealing with 1000 lines or less, it's in the noise. Agree on the quoting, that was just omitted due to the one-word input -- but it should be there for generalization.

Comment: On my machine it takes 4.81 secs for 100,000 lines :-). FWIW potong's GNU sed solution (unsurprisingly since this is what sed is best for) took 0.17 secs while my GNU awk one took 0.98 secs and reichharts POSIX awk one only took 0.22 secs. Agreed on the "if you're dealing with 1000 lines or less..." BUT then you'd be looking for some other reason to use it over sed or awk. I'm only commenting because you said `when use is limited to builtins, it doesn't fall too far behind` as it does still fall very far behind.

Comment: I used `/usr/lib/dict/words` for the test `305089-words` (`3.481s` total). I'm not saying its faster, you know that. The `"not too far behind"` could better be expressed as `"not near as bad as calling an additional utility inside the loop"`. `awk` solution `(1.833s total)` same file, run in subshell redirected to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(...\)./\u\1#/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Cyrus' or Potong's answers are the preferred ones. (For Linux or systems with GNU sed because of \U or \u.)

This is just an additional solution with awk because you mentioned it and used also awk tag:

```
$ echo 'football'|awk '{a=substr($0,1,1);b=substr($0,2,2);c=substr($0,5);print toupper(a)b"#"c}'
Foo#ball
```

This is a most simple solution without RegEx. It will also work on non-GNU awk.

Comment: Let me phrase it differently :-) : AFAIK I am not using any "GNU extension". Thus the solution should be most compatible.

Comment: Thanks. First of all I was not sure about the compatibility and second I was not sure about the (english) language. :-) Updated it.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ echo 'football' | awk 'match($0,/(.)(..).(.*)/,a){$0=toupper(a[1]) a[2] "#" a[3]} 1'
Foo#ball
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case it's kinda overkill though so if this is really all that needs to be done then in reality I'd have to go with [@potongs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55778740/1745001) if you have GNU tools and if you don't then [@reichharts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777394/1745001).

Answer (score 0):

This should work with any version of `awk`:

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        # Note that string indexes start at 1 in awk !
        $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) "" substr($i,2,1) "#" substr($i,3)
    }
    print
}' file
```

Note: If a word is less than 3 characters long, like *`it`*, it will be printed as `It#`

Comment: "different word in each line": That means that only one word is used per line. Your solution also works on multiple words in one line.

Comment: True. Well, it works also if there is just one word in each line. :)

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/^(\w)(\w\w)\w/\U\1\E\2#/' d
```